# Centos help optimize Apache and kernel

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, optimization

I am looking for tips/articles on how to optimize CentOS for production use
I will have 2 servers
1 web server where haproxy will also running
Haproxy will be in front of apache and will be proxying requests either to apache or socket io
Socket io will be running in another server along with MySQL
Basically, the web server will be handling a lot of connections, so I need to make sure that at least the kernel is optimized to handle these.

My systems knowledge is limited, as I am a software engineer but I have experience messing with linux.
Any tips or articles you can recommend?

Any tips on optimizing apache prefork will be also much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The guides here are excellent;

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/community_tags/centos

Specifically make sure you cover at least the basics of hardening the OS against common attacks (SSH in particular, but FTP too).  I'd go with something like CloudFlare if you're going to be getting a huge amount of traffic as at the moment you have two single points of failure and no resilience.

Another option would be to use NGINx as it handles large numbers of connections very well.

Comment: Thanks. Went over them quickly but unfortunately the articles do not contain something for my case

Comment: Ah okay, sorry it didn't help.